# Two tab navigators in one page in Ionic 2 (beta-11)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to find any examples for Ionic 2 where there are 2 Tab navigators in the same page but with no luck.

I currently have 1 Tabber as my root navigators and then I would like to have another tab menu under it (like a sub-menu) which would be visible only on a specific page.

So I added another tabs view in the `<ion-content>` of that page but that destroyed all my CSS - it moved the ion-content to `absolute:0` and would not even show the newly added tabs menu.

It's just as shot in the dark but has anyone managed to achieve something similar to what I am trying?

(I know there are many examples for Ionic 1, but it's not compatible with 2)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid nested tabs. Because nested that layout will become a mess with the css and will be harder to maintain.

Try segments, this will simplify the layout

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#segment382

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you can use  `select(index|tab)` method of `Tabs`. At first, get the ref of the `Tabs`. About how to get ref of `Tabs`, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474184/966698)