# setRoot for Tab pages in Ionic 2+

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have two maps. Each map is on its own view. I am using tabs to jump from view to view. However, when I use this method of navigation, the root is not being set and the page is not being pushed or popped or set once it has been visited. This is an issue with the google maps I am using. This functionality doesn't seem to take place when I am using a regular menu with set root in the menu area. Please Help. Thanks.

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="tab1Title"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="tab2Title"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.ts

```
export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root: any = Tab1Root;
  tab2Root: any = Tab2Root;

  tab1Title = "title1";
  tab2Title = "title2";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the navigation between tabs with code, you can do it like this.
You should use `select(index|tab)` method of `Tabs`. You can get the ref of `Tabs` in your tab pages. like

```
<ion-tabs #theTabs selectedIndex="{{tabIndexNum}}" class="customer-tab">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabsHideOnSubPages]="true"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"[tabsHideOnSubPages]="true"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Then in component, using `@ViewChild('theTabs') tabRef: Tabs` to get ref to the `Tabs` instance.

[Updated]
And for google map, if you want to use it in SPA like angular, ionic, you should call it's init method in the init function of component.

Comment: Confused what the component would look like in this situation because as I have it, I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following example

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="mySelectedIndex">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="tab1Title"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="tab2Title"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root: any = Tab1Root;
  tab2Root: any = Tab2Root;

  tab1Title = "title1";
  tab2Title = "title2";

  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    this.mySelectedIndex = navParams.data.tabIndex || 0;
  }

}
```

Add following code in menu.ts(app.ts) file for navigation

```
openPage(page) {
    let params = {};

    if (page.index) {
      params = { tabIndex: page.index };
    }
}
```

I hope its work for you.